# Getting average of data with multiple entries for a single date using Pivot table in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, pivot-table

I have tried this, but I am unsuccessful.
I have the data dump in an excel sheet (Excel 2010). The first column has month. The second has the dates. The third column has numerical data. I have applied filters on each column to get the data on the Pivot Table. There are entries for each date. There are sometimes multiple entries for a single date.
Now, when I run the Pivot, I get the proper sum, but when I select average, the average is accurate only for the single entries associated with a date. I need to calculate average of multiple data entries for a single date.
Here is an example:

November  11/1/13   30
November  11/2/13   25
November  11/3/13   20
November  11/3/13   25

Now, when I run the Pivot table and select to average the data, it calculates the average as **(30+25+20+25)/4 = 20** (since there are 4 entries, so the sum gets divided by 4)

This is not desirable.

I require the calculation to be made as taking the 3rd and 4th entry as one for the date 11/3/13. So, the required output is **(30+25+(20+25))/3 = 33.33**.

I hope the example gives an clear idea of the requirement. I need a solution for this. How do we modify the Pivot so that the average is calculated not based on just the number of entries, but the average is calculated for the number of days.

Your suggestions are welcome.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/o77n3srmopg6ctf/NTvYTggUrW
I have my file here. As you can see, in the Pivot, I have selected MB's data. I need the average as 27.25, and not 19.81.
The denominator for average must be the number of days, and not the number of entries. MB's sum is 218. I need the answer as 218/8= 27.25, and not as 218/11= 19.81.
Kindly provide a solution. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a column to the source data that calculates the distinct dates per Excecutive. Enter this formula in G2

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT(($B$2:$B2=B2)*($C$2:$C2=C2))>1,0,1)
```

Copy down. Call the column DistinctDates. Go to the Pivot table and change the data source to include column G. Refresh the pivot table. That one is important, so I repeat it: Refresh the pivot table!

Now create a calculated field. In the Pivot Table Tools, click the drop-down for Fields, Items & Sets and create a calculated field.

[image]

Call the field MyAverage and enter the formula

```
='Products passed for packaging' /DistinctDates
```

Add that field to the pivot table as a summed field. The rows will now show the item totals, but the total row will show the averages based on the count of days, not on the count of items.

In the screenshot I have turned on sub-totals for Executives, which are displayed on the same row

[image]